# Automatically insert version/rename file name on update without query string

Tags: php, wordpress, browser-cache, cache-control

I've tried to find out whether this is possible or not (and whether it's a good idea), but without any luck.

When updating a file in Wordpress, let's say `custom.js`, is it then possible to add a version to the file by editing the filename, without using a query string? Or is it a lost cause, considering that one would have to re-enqueue the file afterwards?

An example could be `custom-ver1.js` based on beforementioned file example.

The reason for my question is that I've experienced some browsers that doesn't look for either updated `eTag` or `last-modified` headers if there's a recent cache (Chrome and IE, Where IE at one point didnt even catch an updated query string). Therefore, any crucial updates are not being pushed through.

Furthermore, adding a query string prevents some browsers from caching the file at all.

Comment: Query strings work, you use a checksum like crc for a version number, which would be *automatic*, you could also use rewrites to avoid the query string and place the version number in the filename, like you want.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yeah query strings do work (apart from that single weird occasion in IE), but they also prevent some browsers from caching the file completely. If I were to rewrite the file name, using rewrites, would that also trigger a refresh of the file, as if the original name was changed? And would you have a suggestion as to how this rewrite could be done?